# jQuery Reverse Unwrapping

Tags: jquery

On my page I have a button that unwraps all the `<article>` from it's containers and after that wrap each one separately into `<section>`.
My question is if it's possible to reverse that action by clicking a button so that all the `<article>` would group back into the same position they were at the beginning?

I've created an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JCERK/9/

Comment: *Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My method just uses jQuery `.clone();` method.

Reference: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mGb3a/)

**jQuery Code:**

```js
var oldWrap = $('#wrapper').clone();


$('#unwrap').click(function() {
    $('article').unwrap();
    $('article').wrap('<section></section>');
});

$('#wrapback').click(function() {

    $('#wrapper').replaceWith(oldWrap);
    oldWrap = $('#wrapper').clone();

});
```

Comment: Good idea, but please put your code in the answer as well. (However, I feel I should point out that your solution isn't currently extensible to multiple blocks of code.)

Comment: That's true, but like a regex... I go by the example jsFiddle provided.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and it should work for now. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. As Blazemonger mentioned the use of `clone();` may not be enough. In that case, [**Alnitak Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11613188/1195891) is **spot-on** for advance requirements. Cheers!

Comment: @arttronics thanks.  I would avoid `.clone()` myself because you end up making very large changes to the DOM.  The `.wrap` and `.unwrap` methods do at least preserve the original `article` elements, and importantly, any event handlers registered on them.

Comment: @Tomarz, that's an about-face to select the better answer. I'll leave this less than stellar answer here so others can also be redirected to [**Alnitak's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11613188/1195891). IMHO, `.clone();` is also higher maintenance if your content changes with unexpected requirements that this `.clone();` method can't handle. Cheers!

Comment: Cool, I'll test both solutions then and decide which one suits my needs best. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to pre-mark each of your `<article>` tags with something that identifies which `<section>` they're in.  Putting this in their `class` would be a good idea, e.g.:

```
$('article').addClass(function() {
    return 'section-' + $(this).parent().index();
});
```

When you wrap them back up you'll need to group them by `class`.

```
$('#wrapback').click(function() {
    $('article').unwrap();
    for (var i = 0; i < sections; ++i) {
        var articles = $('article.section-' + i);
        articles.wrapAll('<section/>');
    }
});​
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/QKLkV/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding some attribute or `.data` to each `article` to group them, then use `.wrapAll`.

Perhaps the easiest approach is to use `addClass` and the index of an `.each` loop, since you can then quickly find all `articles` with a given class and wrap them together.

One implementation:

```
$('#unwrap').on('click', function() {
    $('section').each(function(i, el) {
        $(this).find('article').addClass('_index_'+i).unwrap();
    });
    $('article').wrap('<section></section>');
});

$('#wrapback').on('click', function() {
    var idx = 0;
    while ($('article._index_' + idx).length) {
        $('article._index_' + idx).unwrap().wrapAll('<section>');
        idx += 1;
    };
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/JCERK/14/

Comment: @arttronics that's a little harsh - a proper UI sample wouldn't allow you to unwrap more than once, nor wrap if you hadn't already unwrapped.

Comment: I'm not going to worry about it, personally -- OP asked for gimme-codez, he'll have to solve the details on his own.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrap them using [`.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/).

The basic code would be this:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/UhWqa/

jQuery:

```
$('#unwrap').click(function() {
    $('article').unwrap()
    $('article').wrap('<section></section>')
})
$("#wrapback").click(function() {
    $("article").unwrap().wrapAll("<section></section>");
});​
```

HTML: Original

CSS: Original

Comment: Not what the OP wanted. They're not in the same groups they were at the beginning.

Comment: I am working on that, i'll be a couple more minutes

Answer (score 0):

[jquery.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) is what you need, but you'll have to distinguish each group of articles (like wrapping them in a div) else the `wrapAll` method will wrap all your articles in one `section`